# Premature exit of an input loop

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

In my program to sort a linked list using selection and bubble sort, `getdata()` is used to get data from the user.

```
getdata()
{
    int val;
    char c;
    struct node *new;

    new = NULL;
    do {
        printf("Enter a value:\n");
        scanf("%d",&val);

        append(&new,val);

        printf("Any more nodes(y/n):\n");
        c=getchar();
    } while(c =='y' || c =='Y');
    start = new;
}
```

But when I run my program the output is

```
Enter a value: 3

Any More Nodes (Y/N): Linked List Before Sorting: 3 
Linked List After Selection Sorting: 3 

Enter a value: 2

Any More Nodes (Y/N): Linked List Before Sorting: 2 
Linked List After Bubble Sorting: 2
```

I'm not able to type "y/n" in it. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Does your problem actually have anything to do with lists or sorting? It sounds like an input processing problem to me. Please edit your title and tags.

Comment: use `fflush(stdin);` after scanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanf("%d", &val);` leaves the newline in the input buffer, so the `getchar()` reads the newline, which is neither `y` nor `Y`, so the loop terminates.

You should probably use:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1)
    break;
```

You should also test the result of `scanf("%d", &val)` to ensure you get a value.

Your function should also be declared with an explicit return type.  For the code shown, that should be `void`.  Note that your code is unnecessarily tied to the global variable `start`.  If you changed the function to `struct node *getdata(void) { …; return new; }` then you could use it more generally.

Answer (score -1):

instead of ***c=getchar();*** try ***cin.get();***